# Global Var value not assigning inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When i mouseenter through the #infobox div the value is not assigned to true . the value is assigned as false always ! But the console.log("in") segment is executed. Is there s anything wrong with my code

```
var infoChk = false;
$("#infobox").mouseenter(function(){
    console.log("in")
    infoChk = true;
});

if(infoChk == false){
    console.log("false")   
}
else{
    console.log("true")
}
```

Comment: You haven't yet moused over the infobox when it does log `false`, do you? The order of the logs (`false`, then `in`) should make clear what happens. Events are asynchronous!

Comment: you should saw `false` first then `in` in your console, which means the variable `infoChk` is assigned after you check it in if statement.

Comment: nah i moused over it ! One more thing the console inside the function is executed and i see "in "

Comment: Your if/else running on document ready/window load (before you can mouseenter). So console.log always tell false. You need to put this if/else inside your mouseenter function.

Comment: @ nikolev : Hmm So what shall i do to assign to true on mouseover and execute the else part ?

Comment: What should i do to execute the if statements after the function execution ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct but you are checking the value of the variable the wrong way.

To show you that your variable is being set correctly you can do like the code below.

```
var infoChk = false;
$("#infobox").mouseenter(function(){
    console.log("in");
    infoChk = true;
    showVariableValue();
});

function showVariableValue() {
    console.log(infoChk);
}
```

You can see it in action [here in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roshiro/Ngcp6/)

Comment: No if i didnt mouseenter i want to infoChk to be false . In your code the function will be called only if i mouse enter into the div

Comment: @user3383301: You cannot predict the future, so the variable can only state *whether you have mouseentered until now*. You clearly haven't when just setting up the handler.

Comment: @user3383301 exactly, the variable will only be set to `true` when you mouseenter your div. If you don't mouseenter the div, your variable will be kept as `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misinterpreted your own code.

The first code block is runned as an event. Every time your mouse enters div#infobox it will be runned. However, the if statement is runned once, returning false. This is because the code is runned immediately and your mouse is most likely OUT of the box.

Try:

```
var infoChk = false;

$("#infobox").mouseenter(function()
{
    infoChk = true;
    console.log('Entered!');
}).mouseleave(function()
{
   infoChk = false;
   console.log('Leaved!');
});
```